# No support authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: aws, key-authentication

I am trying to connect to my ubuntu instance after rebooting it up off of AWS. The public IPv4 address changed, and I updated the Host Name on PuTTY expecting it to connect like it always does after the IP changes, but I constantly get this error

```
No support authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

I made sure it is using the right ppk/pem key and still get the error.

I understand that PuTTY cannot use pem, but my AWS says "The key used to launch this instance `filename.pem`". Either way, I get an error. I can not connect to the instance on AWS as root either, I get the error "There was a problem setting up the instance connection".

Comment: On Putty, you can go to Session > Logging and enable the 'SSH packets' option to see more details. You'll need to specify a location for the log file as well. Once the configuration is done, try to connect and recreate the issue.

Comment: @Haxiel I enabled that option and when I try to connect to my instance the line "Error writing session log (SSH packets mode) to file: putty.log".
Edit: Ah I see what you mean, I opened the putty.log in a txt and see a few errors. I think the main is the "Server refused our key"

Comment: That's good progress. Since you're trying to connect to an Ubuntu system, can you check [this QA](https://askubuntu.com/q/306798/612676) and see if it helps? Apparently Ubuntu is a little strict/weird about how the keys should be set up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the openssh log (On CentOS it is `/var/log/secure` ) to determine what specific reasons that sshd refuses the connection.